# HOw to use Thunderbird parallel in Ubuntu and in Windows 10

Tags: email

How can one integrate Thunderbird mail accounts so that they are displayed as well in Ubuntu and in Windows 10. Will say: if I download them in Ubuntu the will be the same like in Windowas 10

Answer (score 2):

You've got a few options...

Option 1 is to setup your email account to use IMAP. IMAP keeps your emails on the server, which allows multiple clients to access it. Be careful you don't lose your local emails - you'll have to move them back to the server if you want to share old emails. This is a better option if you want to add other devices in the future. Read more about [Thunderbird and IMAP](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/imap-synchronization).

Option 2 is specific to your local machine where you [share your profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Sharing_a_profile_between_Windows_and_Linux) via a common file location.